# Sum dataframe column with multiple categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with product sales and a column that shows what category they belong to.
Some products belong to more than one category. From this dataframe, I want to create a new one that I can load to tableau that will sum the sales for each of the categories?

[Curent dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNa04.png)

```
Country Sales   Product Categories
A   800 Q   z,y
A   300 W   z
B   400 E   z
B   100 R   x
B   200 T   x,y
```

[Desired dataframe:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNB9a.png)

```
Categories  Country Sales
z   A    1,100 
x   A    -   
y   A    800 
z   B   400
x   B   300
y   B   200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) after [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on `categories`, and [`pandas.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) it back into `df`,
- [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `['Categories', 'Country']`, [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) the groups,
- [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with `fill_value='-'`, [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) again, and finally [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
>>> (df.assign(Categories=df.Categories.str.split(','))
       .explode('Categories')
       .groupby(['Categories', 'Country'], sort=False)
       .sum().unstack(-1, fill_value='-')
       .stack().reset_index())

  Categories Country Sales
0          z       A  1100
1          z       B   400
2          y       A   800
3          y       B   200
4          x       A     -
5          x       B   300
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could split your values and and use `melt` and `groupby`

```
df1 = df.join(
    df["Categories"].str.split(",", expand=True).drop("Categories", 1)
```

---

```
new_df = pd.melt(df1, 
                id_vars=["Country", "Product", "Sales"], value_name="Categories")\
        .groupby(["Categories", "Country"]
        )["Sales"].sum()

Categories  Country
x           B           300
y           A           800
            B           200
z           A          1100
            B           400
```

---

Another method would be to use `explode`

```
df.assign(Categories=df['Categories'].str.split(',')).explode('Categories')\
            .groupby(
                ["Categories", "Country"]
            )["Sales"].sum()


Categories  Country
x           B           300
y           A           800
            B           200
z           A          1100
            B           400
```